# Adding even padding around each line of a heading?

Tags: html, css, padding

i'm making a new site where the headings have backgrounds around them and a little padding.

This is a responsive site, so in some states the headings will break into multiple lines, resulting in them losing the padding to the right on the first line, and to the left on the second line. I am using display:inline since the padding needs to be adjusted around each line.

Is there any way to keep the padding when breaking lines?

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/gmW5X/

The padding is missing after *introducing* and before *the* ...

This does not need to scale down to old ie since the problem only appears at the mobile css targeted to primarely iphone. However, i'd very much like not to alter too much html :/

Answer (score 0):

I don't see another solution but wrap each word in span... http://jsfiddle.net/gmW5X/4

Comment: problem is i dont know where line-break will occur since it breaks on different places depending on the device :/

Comment: yeah if i add a separate tag inside the headings i need to know beforehand where the line breaks will be? Also, they will come from a cms :/

Answer (score 0):

```
display: inline-block;
```

do the trick.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmW5X/5/)